# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)

Tags: vb.net

I have a process that runs every morning looping through thousands of records and establishing whether they can be deleted or not.  I sometimes see this exception in the log file:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)
```

I have read a potential solution here: http://wishmesh.com/2013/10/solution-for-a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-receiving-results-from-the-server/

I know that the SQLDataReader class implements IDisposable as documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx.  Therefore you should either wrap it in USING statements or call .close once you have finished with it.

What happens if you do not call .close?  I do not understand why it could cause this exception as I thought a data reader was simply a collection of objects already returned from the database and stored in memory.

Comment: No, data reader is not a collection of objects, it's a sequential, one-way adapter to access records in the returned query + some caching mechanism. If you ask to read 100000 records, but only need 1000 of them, the other 99000 don't get returned. Number may be off because of caching, so it may read slightly more than you need, because it expects you to eventually read it all, but the idea stands. It reads more as you ask for more, not all at once. What's the logic behind deleting a record? You may be better off using a DELETE SQL query, performance wise (and no leaks).

Comment: Simplest explanation is that the SQL server was restarted.  And the bug in your code is you holding on to the connection too long.  Always create the connection before you start, dispose/close it when you're done.

Comment: @Hans Passant, thanks.  The error occurs nearly every day now and I can confirm that the server is certainly not restarted every day.  I found a data reader that was not closed properly (not wrapped in USING statement).  I guess this could be the cause?