# Count open datareaders/connections

Tags: sql, sql-server

I recently asked the following question: [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27347867/system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-0x80131904).  I had a look through the code and I did find a datareader that was not closed properly.

I am still seeing this exception occasionally in the log file.  Is there a way to count how many open connections/datareaders there are to a database? I have tried the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT DB_NAME(dbid) AS DBName,
       COUNT(dbid)   AS NumberOfConnections,
       loginame      AS LoginName,
       nt_domain     AS NT_Domain,
       nt_username   AS NT_UserName,
       hostname      AS HostName
FROM   sys.sysprocesses
WHERE  dbid > 0
GROUP  BY dbid,
          hostname,
          loginame,
          nt_domain,
          nt_username
ORDER  BY NumberOfConnections DESC;
```

It always returns one connection (the one I have open in SQL Studio Manager I assume).  Why is this? Is it a permissions issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT login_name, [program_name], COUNT(session_id) AS [session_count]
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WITH (NOLOCK)
GROUP BY login_name, [program_name]
ORDER BY COUNT(session_id) DESC OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still returns one row.  It must be a permissions issue.  I will speak to the DBA.